# error in code "check is email after split "

Tags: php

this is the code

```
<?php
function is_email($input) {
  $email_pattern = "/^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]{1,})+@+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]{1,})+\.+([a-z]{2,4})$/i";
  if(preg_match($email_pattern, $input)) return TRUE;

}
$emails = "xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com
xx@xx.com";
$split_emails = split("\n",$emails);
$split_n = count($split_emails);
for ($x=0;$x<$split_n;$x++) {
if(is_email($split_emails[$x]){
echo $split_emails[$x];
}
}
?>
```

i'am sure that the function work right because i tested it in one email 
p.s : the $emails is from "POST Form" , but i edit it to put it here with no HTML codes ,
i guess that the error in the split , so please any help ?

Comment: Why not use `filter_var()`?

Comment: And why not use `explode()`? - `split()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `explode` instead of `split` and you also need to trim empty spaces with `trim` and you can use `filter_var` to validate your email

```
$emails = explode("\n", $emails);
foreach ( $emails as $email ) {
    $email = trim($email);
    filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) and print($email . "\n");
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/13952)

Comment: why i should use explode instead of split ?

Answer (score 1):

I copied it to usbwebserver to test it.

First error is found on line 28 where you not close the if statement.

```
if(is_email($split_emails[$x]){
```

should be

```
if(is_email($split_emails[$x])){
```

further than that I can't go because of split statement is deprecated

*see the example from baba for a better email validation*

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `explode()` instead of `split`.
2. Testing email using regex is discouraged as PHP provides `filter_var()`.

---

```
$split_emails = explode( "\n",$emails );
foreach( $split_emails as $mail )
  echo filter_var( $mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
```